# Controlling cache in a web app using backbone.js and require.js

Tags: backbone.js, glassfish-3, browser-cache

I inherited an app that uses backbone.js and require.js. I wanted to cache CSS, Images and JS files on the browser for infinite time and did not want to cache HTML. So, when I have any changes to the CSS or JS or images I can update the query parameter in the HTML and the browser would fetch the latest version of the asset.

Our app is on Glassfish 3.1.2 so I could not use mod_headers like in Apache to control the behavior. What I ended up doing was add a filter and add Cache-control response header to all css, js and images. This works for css and images fine but all those models and collections that are a result of using backbone.js are not being updated. Well, I could not figure out how to erase them from the cache if I have an updated version on the server.

Any pointers on this issue would help me figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use bust ( [look here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs) ), so when you have a new version, just update it's version in bust, something like this in production.

> urlArgs: "bust=" +  v2

and all older js stuff will be fetched again.

Cheers !

Comment: Thank you. I set the  "bust" on require object before using it like so: <script>
        var require = {
            urlArgs : "bust=r10"
        };
</script>